# How to get distinct values in other columns per value in the primary column

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count, group-by

I'm a beginner in oracle and I can't seem to do this
I'm trying to do the following

From:

```
Col1 | Col2 |  Col3
--------------------
Mike | Tree | Acacia
Mike | Tree | Life
Mike | Tree | Seed
Mike | Plant| Seed
Mike | Tree | Seed
```

To:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3
------------------
Mike | 2    | 3
```

I could not seem to grasp how to do this.

I tried

```
SELECT Col1, COUNT(distinct Col2) , COUNT(distinct Col23)
from TABLE 
GROUP BY COL1,COL2,COL3
```

What shows up is

```
Col1 | Col2| Col3
-----------------
Mike | 1   | 1
Mike | 1   | 1
Mike | 1   | 1
Mike | 1   | 1
Mike | 1   | 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `group by` clause specifies which distinct values you'd like to keep (having the other select list items aggregate terms). Per distinct combination of `col1, col2, col3`, there's of course only one different `col2` or `col3`, which explains why all your results are `1`. To make a long story short - only `col1` should be in the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT   col1, COUNT(DISTINCT col2) , COUNT(DISTINCT col3)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY col1
```

Comment: I get it now! Thanks!